# Deleting Blobs from azure storage mvc

Tags: asp.net, azure, model-view-controller, azure-storage

When trying to delete, or copy a blob from my Azure storage, after successfully uploading it, I get the following 404 error. I cannot see why it is not finding the blob from my storage system, due to successfull upload and successfull downloading. Here is my code to delete that does not work;
I tried setting the "            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(path);
" to a file I knew was there "2020Resume.pdf" and it still didnt work

```
// GET: DocumentUps/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            DocumentUps documentUps = db.DocumentUps.Find(id);
            Distributee distributees = db.Distributees.Find(id);
            if (documentUps == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(documentUps);
        }

        // POST: DocumentUps/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        DocumentUps documentUps = db.DocumentUps.Find(id);
        Distributee distributees = db.Distributees.Find(id);


        string attachmnt = documentUps.Attachment.ToString();
        if (attachmnt.Contains('.'))
            attachmnt = attachmnt.Substring(0, attachmnt.LastIndexOf('.'));

        var fileName = documentUps.DocumentId.ToString() + documentUps.RevisionId.ToString() + attachmnt;

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("filestorageideagen_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("documentuploader");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        blob.Delete();


        if (distributees != null)
        {
            db.Distributees.Remove(distributees);
        }
        db.DocumentUps.Remove(documentUps);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1399
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) +1150

[StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) +4559
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.Delete(DeleteSnapshotsOption deleteSnapshotsOption, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) +62
   Integrated_Project.Controllers.MyDocumentUpsController.DeleteConfirmed(Int32 id) +336
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters of [GetBlockBlobReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682596.aspx) is blob name. So please try to use blob name instead of path.

`CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);`

Comment: Please take a look at this link @TerryFei , its a screen shot of having the exact name required, but still getting the error. It seems the only way to have it work is to manually enter the exact file name

https://gyazo.com/5cb43242be8e8fbb37c0e22aedf843b5

Comment: According to your screenshot, the type is XML.  I assume your blob name is 4747userSettings.xml. Please uncheck `Hide extensions for known file types`  on your local machine and check again, more details please refer to [document](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-file-extensions-in-windows).

Answer (score 4):

There's an issue with the way you're creating an instance of `CloudBlockBlob`. The `path` should only include the file name and not the complete URL as the URL will be created automatically by the SDK. So if you do just the following, the error should go away:

```
            string path = "https://filestorageideagen.blob.core.windows.net/documentuploader/" + fileName;


            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("filestorageideagen_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("documentuploader");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);//Changed path to fileName
            blob.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was in the database query, my revision ID was being changed to 0 and some point and was not searching for the correct file